# Выдать  в подотчет - можно  ли так сказать?

Tags: употребление-слов

У нас одна из секретарей все время пишет "выдать в подотчет", "перечислить в подотчет". Я всегда думала, что выдают под отчет. Но в словаре-то есть этот самый "подотчёт"! Подскажите, как пользоваться этим словом? А то, что пишет секретарь, имеет право на жизнь?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"Подотчет" - бухгалтерское сокращение от *подотчетная сумма*. Ни в каком другом значении использовать нельзя.

Выдать или получить *подотчет* можно. Но это не в значении "как" или "куда" - это **"что"**: *Выдать подотчет в размере ста рублей*. Примерно как "командировочные" - это, кстати, случай такого подотчета.

"Выдать деньги подотчет" неверно, поскольку здесь "подотчет" - означало бы не "что", а "как", "на каких условиях". Совсем уж чудовищно звучит "выдать в подотчет". Не считаю это устаревшим, это, имхо, всегда было неправильно. Может и ошибаюсь, но чутье так подсказывает.

Поэтому вы совершенно правы, утверждая, что *деньги* выдают *под отчет*.

К чести бухгалтеров, они в массе этот момент чувствуют и используют "подотчет" обычно правильно.

Comment: Уважаемый behemothus, как бы чудовищно это ни звучало, но в бухучёте и аудите этот термин есть.Его, например, использует эксперт службы Правового консалтинга ГАРАНТ государственный советник РФ 3 класса Семенюк Александр:http://www.garant.ru/consult/budget/446343/   2)…выдача (перечисление) подотчетной суммы допускается только при отсутствии за подотчетным лицом задолженности по денежным средствам, полученным ранее в подотчет (п. 214 Инструкции N 157н*(3), п. 4.4 Положения N 373-П*(4));

Comment: Раньше даже заявления так писали, на одном бухгалтерском форуме и сейчас советуют:http://www.assessor.ru/forum/index.php?t=1800 Примерная Форма бланка заявления на выдачу денег в подотчет
http://www.glavbyh.ru/showthread.php?t=41621

Answer (score 2):

Правильно: выдать деньги под отчет и денежные средства в подотчет

Например: "Денежные средства в подотчет выдаются по расходным кассовым ордерам и должны расходоваться строго по назначению. Кроме того, подотчетные денежные средства не могут быть отнесены к доходам физического лица - работника общества. При этом расходы подотчетного лица, произведенные в валюте, пересчитываются в рубли по курсу ЦБ РФ, установленному на дату утверждения авансового отчета" (смотрите [здесь](http://www.intalev.ru/agregator/press/id_82857/)).

ПОЯСНЕНИЕ

Существует бухгалтерский термин подотчет.

"Подотчет — это собственно подотчетная сумма, сами деньги. Нюанс заметен в примерах: сотрудник взял в кассе подотчет, равный 5000 руб.; я положила в кошелек 5000 руб. подотчета; он вернул остаток подотчета — 1000 руб" (подробнее [здесь](http://www.glavbukh.ru/art/15183)).

Такие выражения ближе к разговорной профессиональной речи.

Денежные средства в подотчет - это также подотчет (другое название). Этот термин кажется более строгим, в данном случае "подотчет" в форме В.п. с предлогом является несогласованным определением для "денежных средств".

ДОПОЛНЕНИЕ

Думаю, что слово "подотчет"  имеет два значения: 1)  подотчетная сумма (сами деньги);  2)  обязательная отчетность в их расходовании.

В этом случае выдать и перечислить  «деньги под отчет»  - это фактически выдать и перечислить   «деньги под отчетность», с условием отчетности.
В то же время подотчетом называется и сама  подотчетная сумма.

Answer (score 1):

Подотчёт - это термин, существительное в значении "подотчётные деньги" и "операция с такими деньгами, статья расходов". Взять деньги *под что?* - под отчёт. *Выдать в подотчёт* - почти устаревшее понятие, означает "выдать по статье "подотчёт", ..." Более современно, Вы правы, *выдать под что?* - под отчёт, но, видимо, секретарь Ваш старой закалки, употребляет по-старому, а вот "перечислить в подотчет" секретарь вполне грамотно употребляет: перечислить деньги, т.е. перевести в статью расходов ПОДОТЧЁТ.

[Толковый словарь](http://dic.academic.ru/dic.nsf/ushakov/947250)

Comment: В нашей версии: "Перечислить Смирнову в подотчет". А не перевести статью расходов. Но если у Смирнова и так уже полно отчетных денег, а надо ему еще добавить - тогда, наверное, правильно.

Answer (score 0):

http://www.consultant.ru/cons/cgi/online.cgi?req=jt&div=LAW&rnd=235642.1035526924&&ts=005646057022039428

Подотчетные лица - лица, получившие денежные суммы под отчет, для последующих расходов в интересах выдавшей их организации. Деньги, выданные подотчетным лицам, называют подотчетными суммами.

Райзберг Б. А., Лозовский Л. Ш., Стародубцева Е. Б. Современный экономический словарь - 6-е изд., перераб. и доп. - М. (ИНФРА-М, 2011)